# Could there exist a Magnetic equivalent to the Schwinger Limit?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, magnetic-monopoles, pair-production

The [Schwinger limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit) is a scale above which the electromagnetic field is expected to become nonlinear.
It's associated with the [Schwinger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_effect) where It is a prediction of quantum electrodynamics (QED) in which electron–positron pairs are spontaneously created in the presence of an electric field, thereby causing the decay of the electric field.

If Magnetic monopoles exist, shouldn't there be a similar equivalent for magnetic fields? And for a specific mass energy for MAgnetic monopoles (E.g. 511Gev) What would the value of the limit be?